# How do I initialize a bitset in array order?

Tags: c++, bitset, std-bitset

A `std::bitset` isn't an integer, it's an array of bits. But when I initialize it with the bits in the correct order (as I would an array), it seems that all of the bits get reversed like an Endian swap.

The pattern I want is:

```
[1] 0 1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  // [1] should be array Element[0].
```

I initialize with this:

```
std::bitset<12> bMyBitset("101011010101");
```

But when I use a function that prints out the array elements, I get this:

```
// Backwards:
[0] = 1, [1] = 0, [2] = 1, [3] = 0, [4] = 1, [5] = 0, [6] = 1, [7] = 1, [8] = 0, [9] = 1, [10] = 0, [11] = 1
```

What I want is this:

```
// Forward:
[0] = 1, [1] = 0, [2] = 1, [3] = 0, [4] = 1, [5] = 1, [6] = 0, [7] = 1, [8] = 0, [9] = 1, [10] = 0, [11] = 1
```

I know I can manually put all the bits backwards in the initializer string, but that is extremely tedious and error prone. I'm looking for a solution where I can put them in the same order that I would when initializing an array, with Element[0] first.

I want to do this:

```
std::bitset<12> bMyBitset {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
// no matching function for call to 'std::bitset<12>::bitset(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

How can I initialize a `bitset` with elements in array order?

Comment: `[0]` is the rightmost bit of a bitset.

Comment: `[0]` is the first element of an array. And if we think of a `bitset` as an array of booleans, there is no "right" or "left", only "first" and "last".  "Right" and "left" only matter if you're trying to print out the set as a string or convert it to an integer.

Comment: A bitset isn't an array though.  It's supposed to model a bit-feild, and in those cases, the 0-th bit is the LSB, or right most bit.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering

Comment: If you want a boolean array that takes advantage of bit packing, then `vector<bool>` will do that, and give you the semantics you want.  It can be a pain to deal with though as `operator[]` returns proxy objects.

Comment: "*`[0]` is the first element of an array*" - `std::map` would like to have a word with you :)

Comment: If you look at the value of a byte of memory as binary, say `01000001`, and you use that value to construct a `bitset`, what order would you expect the bits to be in? What value should `[0]` have?

Comment: I'm okay with `Element[0]` being the LSB as stored in the bitset and as displayed in `cout`, but for reasons of sanity, I'd like to *initialize* the bitset by specifying LSB first and MSB last, because that matches the pattern of the data the bitset represents.